# How can we get trigger names for particular table?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to find in MySQL database that this table have this trigger?

How can we get trigger names for particular table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select TRIGGER_NAME from information_schema.triggers where EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = 'MY_TABLE';
```

Comment: Trigger is a schema-scoped object.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them the [information_schema triggers table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers-table.html)